# PasswordSignInAsync returns result. Succeeded as unsuccessful for users with RequiresTwofactor as true

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

```cs
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(loginUser.UserName, loginUser.Password,
                    loginUser.RememberMe, false);  //LAST  value of lockout is set in Startup.cs

if (result.Succeeded)
{
    // not reaching here if RequireTwoFactor is true and succeeded is coming false
}
```

I have created a Identity app and I am trying to put two factor auth. It was working fine. When I assigned a token to the new user on first MFA setup and made him login using the code on the mobile phone .Then made him **SetTwoFactorEnabledAsync**.. When I logged out and tried to login again with the API, the API is not putting Succeeded in the result variable when the user is RequiresTwoFactor as true

Comment: Well surely they haven't yet succeeded. I assume `result.RequiresTwoFactor == true` though?

Comment: Then how do we make it succeeded? The user had credentials right but still its not succeeded and after we redirect the user for code verification, we actually did not complete the login function, roles and claims needed to be checked as well in later (result.succeeded) method.. how will we check those things if we redirect the user to code verify page?

Comment: Having gathered the code from the user, and called `TwoFactorAuthenticatorSignInAsync`, *that* result should be `Succeeded`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever But what if our logic for checking Roles and claims are in this **result.Succeeded** check? If RequiresTwoFactor will send us to other API and then using `TwoFactorAuthenticatorSignInAsync`, we can get succeeded but the logic which is in Login API within result.Success method, how will we run that? do we have to rewrite the logic to verify roles in Code checking API? I dont think so?

Comment: @DavidG can you please help me with above query?

Comment: Then you move that logic to somewhere it makes sense that it can be called *either* immediately after the `PasswordSignInAsync`, **or** after `TwoFactorAuthenticatorSignInAsync`, depending on which of them returns `Success`. It's not that tricky a concept.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I know sir but I want to know the best practice to do it? I do not think calling to check roles from 2 different API's seems a decent approach.. But I am not sure... what would you suggest the correct way to do this kind of login?